# Detect intersections between an `AABB` and a `CollisionShape3D`

Tags: collision-detection, godot, 3d-meshes

I thought this would be a simple matter of getting the mesh that defines the `CollisionShape3D` and checking if any of the triangles of the mesh intersect with the `AABB`, but that didn't work. Let me explain.

I'm doing some custom volumetric 3D pathfinding in Godot 4. For this, I need to loop over all the `CollisionShape3D`s in a scene and check if they're in some region of space defined by an `AABB`.

I thought I'd loop over each `CollisionShape3D`, get its mesh, loop over each surface in the mesh, use `MeshDataTool` to loop over the faces in the surface, and then finally check each face for a collision with the `AABB`:

```py
func check_for_colliders_in_aabb(colliders: Array[CollisionShape3D], box: AABB):
    for collider in colliders:
        var mesh = collider.shape.get_debug_mesh()
        for surface_idx in range(mesh.get_surface_count()):
            var mdt = MeshDataTool.new()
            mdt.create_from_surface(mesh, surface_idx)
            for face_idx in mdt.get_face_count():
                # Check if the face intersects with the AABB
```

But nothing happens. Specifically, I've figured out that `mdt.get_edge_count()` and `mdt.get_face_count()` both return zero. Also, while `mesh.get_aabb()` returns a correct-looking AABB, `mesh.get_faces()` returns an empty list.

I think this might be because the "primitive type" of the mesh is wrong. When I check `mesh.surface_get_primitive_type(0)`, the primitive type I get back is `1` which corresponds to `PRIMITIVE_LINES`, so I guess the mesh doesn't have any triangles, and therefore no faces? Each `CollisionShape3D` is just using a `BoxShape3D` as it's shape, no other adjustments have been made from the default `CollisionShape3D`.

Note that checking if any of the vertices/edges are in the `AABB` is NOT an option, because the faces of the `CollisionShape3D`s can be quite big, and my `AABB`s quite small so it's entirely possible that an `AABB` could be bisected by a face of a `CollisionShape3D` without any of the edges/vertices of that face actually intersecting with the `AABB`.

Is it possible to convert the mesh into one that does have triangles so that I can check each of the triangles for a collision with the `AABB`? If this is not possible, how would I check if some `CollisionShape3D` is intersecting/colliding with some `AABB`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll suggest to check the collision using Godot physics below.

But first, about the mesh you are getting...

---

### The Debug Mesh

It makes sense that you get lines from `get_debug_mesh`. The documentation says:

> Returns the ArrayMesh used to draw the debug collision for this Shape3D.

Which, yes, it is a mesh, it does not have triangles. For reference, this is how a `CollisionShape3D` with a `BoxShape3D` is drawn in the engine:

[image: CollisionShape3D with a BoxShape3D]

No triangles. *Yes, that is what you are getting.*

---

### On the conversion of a Shape to a Mesh

> Is it possible to convert the mesh into one that does have triangles so that I can check each of the triangles for a collision with the AABB?

Not really. The primitive shapes are not meshes internally, which allows for some optimizations.

Consider, for example, an `SphareShape3D`... If it were a mesh internally physics would have to checks tons of faces for it, but being an sphere handled as an special case allows to check collision based on the distance to the center, which makes one of the fasters colliders, if not the fastest.

Of course, you could go into the trouble of approximating them with meshes. The easier way to go about is probably to check the type, and use one of the built-in mesh types (A `BoxMesh` for `BoxShape3D`, a `SphereMesh` for a `SphareShape3D` and so on).

---

### Checking the collision from code

> If this is not possible, how would I check if some CollisionShape3D is intersecting/colliding with some AABB?

I believe the easier way is to create a collider with a `BoxShape3D` for you AABB and orquestarte Godot to check the intersectation.

For this is better to avoid using `Node`s (after all, if you drop a collider in the scene tree, other things might detect it, which might be problematic for the game).

Instead, let use `PhysicsDirectSpaceState3D`, which you can get from any `Node3D` like this:

```
var space := get_world_3d().direct_space_state
```

And now we have a few options for what we want:

- `collide_shape`: Returns contact points.
- `intersect_shape`: Returns a dictionary with collision information.
- `cast_motion`: unlike the other two, this one tests if moving the shape will collide. In other words: It is a a shape cast.

It is unclear to me exactly what you need, so I'll refer you to the documentation of `PhysicsDirectSpaceState3D`.

Regardless, they are both used similarly, you need to pass an `PhysicsShapeQueryParameters3D` and the maximum number of results you want, as arguments, in that order.

You can create the `PhysicsShapeQueryParameters3D` like this (here I'm setting some properties to their default values for illustration purposes):

```
var query := PhysicsShapeQueryParameters3D.new()
query.collide_with_areas = false
query.collide_with_bodies = true
query.collision_mask = 4294967295
```

It is important that you set `transform` and `shape`, so let us get them from our `AABB` (I'm assuming the `AABB` is in global coordinates):

```
var box_shape := BoxShape3D.new()
box_shape.size = aabb.size
query.transform = Transform3D.IDENTITY.translated(aabb.get_center())
query.shape = box_shape
```

And we can query (`collide_shape` in this case):

```
var result := space.collide_shape(query, 32)
prints(result)
```

Comment: Thanks! Quick question: what is a "debug collision"? I'm going to read up about `PhysicsDirectSpaceState3D` and try implement this. I'll accept your answer if it works out (which I think it will)

Comment: @beyarkay Thinking about it "debug collision" is bad wording... But this is what they meant: When you enable visible collision shapes from the Debug menu you will get the colliders rendered in the game. The mesh used for that is the one you get with `get_debug_mesh`, and it is also used in the editor as in the screen capture I shown in the answer.